# Радиус круга и позиция курсора мышки

Tags: javascript, геометрия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть серый круг. Нужно отловить `mousemove` в радиусе 5–10px от него, как показано на картинке зеленой окружностью.

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы круг плавно «уходил» от позиции курсора: если я вожу курсором поверх круга, он плавно уходит вниз в зависимости от позиции курсора, если вести курсор справа налево, то круг должен уходить не влево, а быть немного «живым» – вниз, направо и т.д.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш текущий код.

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял задачу - круг должен убегать в противоположную от курсора сторону.

Вам нужна разница координат середины круга и курсора.

Это - вектор `(DX, DY)`. Условимся, что он исходит из центра круга до курсора:

`DX = DXm-DXc`, `DY = DYm-DYc` (Индексы с - центр круга, m - мышь).

Вам нужно из этого вектора получить вектор направления единичной длины - для этого обе координаты вектора делите на длину (модуль) вектора `L = sqr(DX**2+DY**2)` ( `**` - возведение в квадрат). Дальше, чтобы двигаться в направлении обратном направлению на курсор, вам нужен обратный вектор, т.е. обе координаты нужно взять с минусом. Потом умножаете обе координаты вектора на нужную скорость убегания и по таймеру прибавляете соответствующие координаты вектора к соответствующим координатам круга, пока курсор находится в заданной области.

Пример.

```
Дано:
Координаты центра круга: Xc, Yc
Координаты курсора мыши: Xm, Ym
Радиус-вектор от центра круга к курсору:
(Xm-Xc, Ym-Yc)
Длина этого вектора:
L = sqrt( (Xm-Xc)**2 + (Ym-Yc)**2 )
Если не понятно как это вычисляется, вспомните теорему Пифагора.
Длина в данном случае - гипотенуза, которую получаем из длин двух катетов.
Вектор направления (длиной 1 ед.) из центра круга к курсору мыши:
(DX, DY), где DX = (Xm-Xc)/L, DY = (Ym-Yc)/L.
Вектор направления, обратного направлению к курсору: (-DX, -DY)
Теперь, допустим, нам нужно переместить центр круга на расстояние H в направлении от курсора мыши.
Тогда нам нужно координатам круга прибавить координаты полученного нами вектора направления, умноженного на расстояние H.
По координатам это будет выглядеть так:
XC = XC - DX * H
YC = YC - DY * H
Что и требовалось.
```

Вообще, гуглите основы векторной алгебры на плоскости, хотя бы для школьников, в жизни может пригодиться.

Comment: можете привести пример, а то как-то не понятно(

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вам было проще и понятнее, сделайте сначала это не на плоскости, а одномерно, вдоль прямой: пусть круг движется только по оси X. И пусть мышь может находиться только справа от круга.

У вас есть: `cx` (коорд. центра круга), `mx` (мышиный X), `rс` радиус круга и `ra` внешний радиус. И возможны, по-простому, два варианта:

- мышь далеко от круга: `mx > (cx + ra)`
- мышь вошла в активную зону, или даже заехала в круг: `mx <= (cx + ra)`

Во втором случае надо двигать круг. Как – много вариантов. Имитировать физику жесткого тела, имитировать удар с деформацией мяча, просто сглаживать движение.

Посмотрите [материалы](http://physicsdemos.liveldi.ru/) к докладу по анимации в JS с недавнего MoscowJS митапа: там как раз мячики, динамика, взаимодействие с мышкой.

[image: скрин]

**Upd.** для практики [написал](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/5tkod02y/) что-то похожее на вашу затею. Лаконично не вышло. Пришлось городить функцию для работы с двухмерными векторами, добавлять силу трения. Попробуйте разобраться в моём жутком коде с комментами на английском. Условие проверки дистанции – строка `if( dist > this.R.o)` и далее.

Comment: Можно пример, если не трудно

Comment: Можно: по ссылке в ответе сплошь примеры. Проявите любопытство.

Comment: В этом и дело, что подобного нет...

Comment: Обновил ответ: добавил «подобный» пример, сделанный на коленке )